# How to append to array only if it doesn't contain value with rethinkDB

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, reql

I'd like to append a value to an array in a record that looks similar to the following:

```
{
  _id: 'foo',
  cols: [
    'abc123',
    '123abc'
  ]
}
```

It's possible that this field doesn't exist and will need to be created prior to appending. I also don't want to append to the array if the value already exists in the array. So far I have the following which satisfies all but the last requirement of not adding duplicate entries.

```
r.table('users')
 .get(userId)
 .update({
   cols: r.row('cols').default([]).append(uuid)
 })
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can try using ```setInsert```
https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/set_insert/
Distinct as far as I know defines that there should be no duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several solutions.

```
r.table('users')
 .get(userId)
 .update({
   cols: r.branch(r.row('cols').default([]).contains(uuid),
                   r.row('cols'),
                   r.row('cols').default([]).append(uuid))
 })
```

Or we can use `setInsert` as @char suggestions

```
r.table('users')
 .get(userId)
 .update({
   cols: r.row('cols').default([]).setInsert(uuid))
 })
```

The issue with `setInsert` is it ensure returning a set. So if you have intentinally put duplicate elements in original `cols`, it will remove dup element.

Comment: Thanks! I Ended up using the setInsert because that's the functionality I need. I'll have to investigate the `branch` method further. Do you know if one of these is more performant?

Comment: Just an FYI, you have an extra ) after the setInsert call. I tried to edit it myself, but for some strange reason stackoverflow won't allow edits of less than 6 characters. Also thanks for this answer, it was also just what I was looking for :)